# Flutter installation can not find android studio even though android studio is installed. (Linux)

Tags: linux, flutter, android-studio

I am getting an error

```
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for detailed instructions).
```

even after I have downloaded Android studio. I use the linux OS (jammy).

I installed flutter using `sudo snap install flutter --classic` then I ran `flutter doctor -v`

I downloaded Android studio from its [official website](https://developer.android.com/studio) and installed it using `sudo snap install android-studio --classic`. The error persists.

So, I tried to manually set the path for android studio, using `flutter config --android-studio-dir=/snap/bin/android-studio`.

I believe the path is correct because `$ whereis android-studio` returned `android-studio: /snap/bin/android-studio`.

I am getting an error: `Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path "/snap/bin/android-studio".`

How to complete my flutter installation? I want to use flutter to develop an android application. I am looking for a solution on the linux OS.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Problem solved. Visit https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager in case you face the same issue.